# onclick button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I try when I click on 1 button to have the value 1 in the first(blank) button but my code doesn't work and the value of first button become 1 before I click

HTML code

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>
      Exemplu
  </title>

  </script>


  </head>
  <body>

<form>
<input type="button" value=""  id= "say_result"/>

</form>


<form>
<input type="button" value="1"  id= "say_one"/>

</form>



<form>
<input type="button" value="2"  id= "say_two"/>
</form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="+"  id= "say_plus"/>
</form>

<form>
<input type="button" value="-"  id= "say_minus"/>
</form>
<form>
<input type="button" value="="  id= "say_equal"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src=exemplu3.js></script>

</body>
  </html>
```

---

Javascript code

```
function cifr(vallue){

var local_Value = vallue;

return  document.getElementById("say_result").value = local_Value;


}

var oneButton = document.getElementById("say_one")
oneButton.onclick = cifr(1);


function two(){
document.getElementById("say_result").value = "2";
return 2;

}

var oneButton = document.getElementById("say_two")
oneButton.onclick = two;
```

Comment: Have you considered adding the missing semicolons and parentheses? ;)

Answer (score 1):

In the following line:

```
oneButton.onclick = cifr(1);
```

You are calling the `cifr` function with the argument `1` and assigning the result to the `oneButton` click event.

This should probably be:

```
oneButton.onclick = function(){cifr(1);};
```